# Use xpath to obtain value

Tags: php, xpath, namespaces

ok so i have this xml:

```
<resin xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin" xmlns:resin="urn:java:com.caucho.resin">
<cluster>
<host host-name="www.1.com">
<host-alias>1.com</host-alias>
<root-directory>c:/docroot</root-directory>
<web-app id="/" document-directory="."/>
</host>
<host host-name="www.2.com">
<host-alias>2.com</host-alias>
<root-directory>c:/docroot</root-directory>
<web-app id="/" document-directory="."/>
</host>
</cluster>
</resin>
```

how do i get( in  php ) the xpath of the host name "www.1.com"
if i use this:

```
$items = $xpath->query(sprintf('//host[@host-name="%s"]', $hostNameToLookFor));
```

without

```
xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin" xmlns:resin="urn:java:com.caucho.resin"
```

it works

please help, its driving me crazy!
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
        $data = <<<xml
<resin xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin" xmlns:resin="urn:java:com.caucho.resin">
<cluster>
<host host-name="www.1.com">
<host-alias>1.com</host-alias>
<root-directory>c:/docroot</root-directory>
<web-app id="/" document-directory="."/>
</host>
<host host-name="www.2.com">
<host-alias>2.com</host-alias>
<root-directory>c:/docroot</root-directory>
<web-app id="/" document-directory="."/>
</host>
</cluster>
</resin>

xml;

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'http://caucho.com/ns/resin');
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('resin', 'urn:java:com.caucho.resin');

        foreach ($xml->xpath ('//ns:host[@host-name="www.2.com"]') as $v)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to var_dump the $v?

Comment: In my primer I used SimpleXMLElement. I am not sure about DOMDocument.

Comment: can you rewrite me the entire function? ( i'm not a programmer, so...)

Comment: Use `$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);` in order to convert your existing DOMDocument into SimpleXMLElement, and then proceed as was shown above.